# How to enable Access Tokens for Implicit Flow in Azure AD Application with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The powershell command New-AzureADApplication only supports one parameter called "Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow" that only enables ID Tokens for Implicit Flow, but there is any parameter to also enable Access Tokens.

Is that supported with Powershell or shall I use the graph api to update that single field ?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure AD Graph API has two attributes for implicit flow:

- `oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` - Enabled ID token issuance in Implicit flow
- `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` - Enables access token issuance in Implicit flow

Of these two, only the second can be set with the current Azure AD PowerShell module:

```
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId "{id}" -Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow $true
```

Enabling or disabling ID token issuance for Implicit flow is not currently possible with the Azure AD PowerShell module. You'd need to do this with Azure AD Graph directly.

Comment: Thanks. Is that going to be fixed in powershell ?

Comment: Yes, thought there is no timeline to share at the moment.

Comment: Is there a timeline on this now? It still doesn't seem possible

Answer (score 1):

Since Microsoft depricated AzureAD powershell module and recommended to use Microsoft.Graph PS module instead I was faced with the same issue, but in a new package.

So, here's solution that was finally working for me:

```
$webApp = New-Object 'Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.MicrosoftGraphWebApplication'

$implicitGrantSettings = New-Object 'Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.MicrosoftGraphImplicitGrantSettings'
$implicitGrantSettings.EnableIdTokenIssuance = $true
$webApp.ImplicitGrantSettings = $implicitGrantSettings

$newAzureAdApp = New-MgApplication `
  -DisplayName $appName `
  -Web $webApp
```

Hope it will be helpful to somebody