# Powershell - Azure AD Application Registration - how to set ID tokens?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-powershell

**Background Information**

I have two separate PowerShell scripts.  One uses an ARM template to deploy a function app, along with storage accounts etc. It runs under the context of a security principle we have set up specifically for the function app.
I'm using the same security principle to run a second Powershell script that creates an AD Application registration.  I've managed to do everything except:

- set up the application so it uses ID Tokens
- add scope
- associate the AD application registration as the identity provider for my function app.

This question is specifically about an error I'm running into while try to set up ID tokens.  but I'm sharing additional information about what has/hasn't been done yet in case it's relevant.

**Problem**

The error that comes up when i try to run my second powershell script is this:

```
===== 6.  Set Application to use ID Tokens ======
Update-AzADApplication_UpdateExpanded: C:\Users\me\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\Az.Resources\5.4.0\MSGraph.Autorest\custom\Update-AzADApplication.ps1:549:5
Line |
 549 |      Az.MSGraph.internal\Update-AzADApplication @PSBoundParameters
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Resource '' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

Here's the code:

```
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $AZ_TENANT_ID -Credential $Credential
Set-Azcontext -Subscription $AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID -Tenant $AZ_TENANT_ID

#What's the function app name? 
$AZ_FUNCTION_APP = az functionapp list `
    -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME `
    -o json | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-output $AZ_FUNCTION_APP.Name

Write-Output "===== 1. Query for AZ Fun Details ======"
#Collect Data about the Function app which we need
$appDeets = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -Name $AZ_FUNCTION_APP.Name
Write-Output $appDeets
$appURL = $appDeets.DefaultHostName

Write-Output "===== 2.  Create New basic AD Application Registration ======"
#Create a New AD Application Registration
$adAppName = $AZ_FUNCTION_APP.Name + "-AdApp"

#define Graph API permissions
$RequiredResourceAccess = @{
  ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000";
  ResourceAccess = @(
      @{
          Id = "guid";
          Type = "Scope"
      },
      @{
          Id = "guid";
          Type = "Scope"
      },
      @{
          Id = "guid";
          Type = "Role"
      }
  )
}

$newAppRegistration = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $adAppName `
    -AvailableToOtherTenants $False `
    -RequiredResourceAccess $RequiredResourceAccess

Write-Output $newAppRegistration

Write-Output "===== 3.  Create secret for the AD Application ======"
#Create a secret for the new application
$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate= $startDate.AddYears(3)
$newSecret = New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $newAppRegistration.AppId -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate
Write-Output $newSecret

Write-Output "===== 4.  Define Redirect URL for AD Application ======"
$redirectURL =  "https://$appURL/.auth/login/aad/callback"
Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $newAppRegistration.AppId -ReplyUrl $redirectURL | Out-Null

Write-Output "===== 5.  Define Application ID URI ======"
#Add Application ID URI
$appIdentifierUri = "api://" + $newAppRegistration.AppId
Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $newAppRegistration.AppId -IdentifierUri $appIdentifierUri | Out-Null

Write-Output "===== 6.  Set Application to use ID Tokens. ======"
Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $newAppRegistration.AppId -Oauth2RequirePostResponse

Write-Output "===== 7.  TODO:  Add Scope ======"

Write-Output "===== 8.  TODO:  Add this AD Application to Function App as the Identity Provider ======"
```

**Screenshots**

Here are two screenshots showing what i'm after / how I do it when I set up the app auth manually:

[image]

This is what the scope looks like when I create it manually:

[image]

Any tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

What I've done so far:

- I've downloaded a copy of the AD Application Registration manifest file before and after enabling the Id Tokens.
  The only difference I can see is the one field:

  "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
- The difference btwn when I do this manually via the GUI and when I do this with the Powershell script is the login / user that's being used.

When I sign in manually to azure portal to create the registration for the function app, the login account has the following roles assigned under the specific subscription:

```
 Owner
 User Access Administrator
```

This is different from the security principle that's being used by Powershell.  Its been added to the subscription as a

```
 contributor
```

Clearly, we don't want to add owner status to this application security principle.  But is there a specific set of permissions needed for a security principle to be able to create another AD application registration?
So far, I've been ok to create and update the AD App reg as you can see from the script.  But I thought I'd ask / table all the info ... in case it helps.

**EDIT 2**

Unfortunately, Azure Active Directory Graph isn't an option for me:

[image]

Is this something I can enable as an admin / owner of the subscription?  Or better yet, since it's being deprecated, how can I do this via Graph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tried the same with our Azure function to add identity (Azure Ad Authentication)  and getting the same error.

[image]

***After did some research concluded that we can do the same with Azure Ad Graph Explorer instead of using PowerShell.***

To do with Azure Ad graph Explorer please refer this [***`SO THREAD`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757068/how-to-setup-oauth2allowidtokenimplicitflow-in-azure-ad-application-from-console) as stated by @[***Joy Wang***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9455659/joy-wang)

We have tried the same and can able to enable the ***ID TOKENS***

[image]

***OUTPUT DETAILS:-***

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:

- SO THREAD: [***How to enable Access Tokens for Implicit Flow in Azure AD Application with PowerShell***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083737/how-to-enable-access-tokens-for-implicit-flow-in-azure-ad-application-with-power)

***UPDATE:-***

There is still time to deprecate Azure AD Graph Explorer , But we can use till June 2022 : ***https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#***

Open the above link and login with your account.

and mention the below API in search bar

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/{object id of the application}?api-version=1.6
```

and in request body :

```
{
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow":true
}
```

For [***Microsoft graph explorer***](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), i could not see any API to enable the ID Token .

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I saw that post you reference before I actually posted my question.  The problem is that I don't have the option to select Azure Active Directory graph.  Please see Edit 2 above.  I'll try to add a screenshot showing what I see.

Comment: As it will be deprecated on june 2022, That is the reason we need to migrate to Microsoft Graph instead of Azure graph explorer. But for automation through API we can enable `ID TOKEN` currently.

Comment: sorry @AjayKumarGhose-MT - just to make sure I understand, are you saying there is no way to do this through MS Graph right now?  The only API that can do this is through the Azure AD Graph API?

Comment: also just out of curiosity, is this also a problem with Access tokens?  Or just ID Tokens?

Comment: Hello @dot, I have not tried with MS graph yet. Let me try and get back here. Its a problem with ID Tokens only. Access token we can do through PowerShell.

Comment: Could you please have a look my Update answer once.

Comment: So two comments first and one question.  The link you have showing how to set the Access Token is using the older Azure powershell.  I'm using the new AZ Powershell modules.  Also it's true that the Azure AD Graph Api is not being deprecated for a few more months but it's not enabled in my subscription for some reason.  I'll try to dig around to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243243/discussion-between-dot-and-ajaykumarghose-mt).

Comment: Marking as answer.  Basically btwn your research and mine; and the comments here and in our discussion, I've been able to confirm that none of the powershell methods work.  And the only way is to enable / use the Active Directory API.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT I've posted an answer on how to do this with MS Graph

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using MS Graph PowerShell and the MS Graph Explorer

**Microsoft Graph PowerShell**

```
$params = @{
    Web = @{
        ImplicitGrantSettings = @{
            EnableIdTokenIssuance = $true
        }
    }
}

# For new applications
New-MgApplication -DisplayName "YOUR_APP_NAME" @params

# For updating existing applications
Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId "YOUR_APP_ID" @params
```

**Microsoft Graph Explorer**

*Method*

`PATCH`

*Endpoint*

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{APP_OBJECT_ID}`

*Request body*

```
{
    "web": {
        "implicitGrantSettings": {
            "EnableIdTokenIssuance": true
        }
    }
}
```